# How do I remove react native firebase notification click action on android?

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, foreground, react-native-firebase

I am using react-native-firebase to set up foreground & background push notifications in my application. I set it up according to the docs: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/notifications/receiving-notifications#App-in-Foreground-and-background

The app has a `firebase.messaging().onMessage()` listener attached and when it receives a notification in foreground, I use `firebase.notifications.displayNotification(notification)` to display the notification.

Then the `onNotificationOpened` listener receives the notification and navigates the user to a different screen.

The problem is that, the notification object received from `onNotificationOpened` has an action `android.intent.action.VIEW` which launches the MainActivity every time it is clicked. I have no idea where this action string is coming from, since neither the client app nor the backend sets any click action.
Also this `android.intent.action.VIEW` happens to be the intent filter action for my `MainActivity`.

I don't want a ContentIntent action tied to my notification, I want my app to handle the navigation to the correct component.

Also there is the problem that clicking on the notification unmounts and re-mounts my main component and that causes the notification listeners to be removed.

I have tried setting MainActivity `android:launchMode=singleTop` in AndroidManifest but the activity still relaunches. I have also tried using `singleTask`, `singleInstance` and `standard`

This is my display notification function that is called `onMessage`

```
export async function displayNotification(message: RemoteMessage) {
  try {
    const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification();

    const { title, message: messageBody, ...messageData } = message.data;

    notification
      .setNotificationId(message.messageId)
      .setTitle(title)
      .setBody(messageBody)
      .setData({
        ...messageData
      })
      .setSound('default');

    if (isAndroid) {
      // Build a channel for notifications on Android

      const channel = await createAndroidChannel();

      notification.android
        .setBigText(messageBody)
        .android.setChannelId(channel.channelId)
        .android.setAutoCancel(true) // Remove on press
    }

    await notifications.displayNotification(notification);
    return notification;
  } catch (error) {

  }
}
```

Expected result is: user has app in foreground > user receives push notification > clicks on notification > does NOT relaunch Main Activity but redirects to particular screen if needed via `onNotificationOpened` listener

Actual result is: after user clicks on foreground notification > Main Activity is relaunched and Main screen re-mounts causing notification listeners to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is there is already an instance of your app running either when your app is in foreground or ink background. So when you press on a notification, it again creates another instance of the mainActivity and relaunches it.To solve this problem you have to understand about the launch modes of android

[Please refer to this link for description](https://medium.com/@iammert/android-launchmode-visualized-8843fc833dbe)

Try setting launchMode as singleTop in AndroidManifest.xml file. Then reinstall and test the application. And this should solve your issue.!